# Unable to set a breakpoints to debug a NuxtJS app in VSCode

Tags: nuxt.js, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to debug a Nuxt.JS app in VSCode, following instructions provided [here](https://medium.com/js-dojo/debugging-nuxt-js-with-vs-code-60a1a9e75cf6) the launch.json file is as follow:

```
{   "version": "0.2.0",   "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "client: chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:///*": "${workspaceRoot}/*"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "server: nuxt",
      "args": ["dev"],
      "osx": {
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/nuxt"
      },
      "linux": {
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/nuxt"
      },
      "windows": {
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js"
      }
    }   ],   "compounds": [
    {
      "name": "fullstack: nuxt",
      "configurations": ["server: nuxt", "client: chrome"]
    }   ] }
```

But trying to set a breakpoint I receive the message:
"breakpoint ignored because generated code not found (source map problem ?)"

I can't figure it out how to further modify the launch.json file or which option to add to nuxt.config.js.

Comment: Try to set [devtool](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2734#issuecomment-410135071) in `nuxt.config.js`

Answer (score 0):

Try this (client only):

`launch.json`:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "pwa-chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  ]
}
```

`nuxt.config.js`:

```js
export default {
  build: {
    // Enable breakpoints
    extend (config, ctx) {
      if (ctx.isDev) {
        config.devtool = ctx.isClient ? 'source-map' : 'inline-source-map'
      }
    }
  }
}
```